# Hide Image On Wordpress On Single Page

Tags: css

Sorry, I know this kind of question has been asked before but I can't quite figure it out.

I'm trying to hide the city image on this page:

http://learnenglish20.com/buy-tokens/

I put this CSS in my child theme:

```
 body.page-id-2557 #title-content { 
 display: none !important;
```

}

I think maybe I've got my class wrong?  Anyway, I'd really appreciate any help

Comment: Welcome to WPSE, @Race Reed.  `title-content ` is a class, not an id. Just change the `#` for a dot (`.`). And, please, remember this CSS related questions, even if are about a WordPress blog, should go to [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Just override the background property with the below code in your child css.

```
#title {
    background: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This would set the background image for all pages to none, it wouldn't be specific for that page.

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this:

```
.page-id-2557 section#title {
   background: none !important;
}
```

This removes the image, then you may want to change the color of the title

Which you'd have to also use !important, since this theme uses !important a lot, which isn't great... try to avoid.

```
.page-id-2557 #title.title-area .title-content .title-text h1 {
    color: #FFA23B !important;
}
```

Comment: He didn't say.   To hide just the image, he'd have to do this: page-id-2557 #title {
    background: none !important;
 } and use !important, since the image itself is declared with the Important and then change the color of the text.

Comment: Good improvement, will delete my comments except this one (till tomorrow).

Comment: This one did it  .                                                                                         page-id-2557 section#title {
   display: none !important;
}  Thanks fellows

Comment: @RaceReed if you like the answer...could you up vote it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to hide the logo image that's displayed instead of the site title.  Check the image element in source code and then add the custom class to the specific element.

A second option would be to create a custom page template, and then use it while publishing that particular page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `background-position` and just move it out of the view of the element.

```
element.class{
  background-position:-9999px;
}
```

or

```
element.class{
  background:transparent;
}
```

Comment: Don´t move it, that´s not a clean solution.

Comment: why this is not a clean solution ? please define

Comment: On the one hand: If you want to hide/remove things you either make them transparent or set them to `display:none`, so they don´t collide with other elements. But that´s more philosophical, perhaps. On the other hand: Have you tried your CSS? It has no effect, as the background image size is set to `cover` and standard browser behaviour is to tile the image then. That´s what happens in my Chrome.

Comment: Ok my friend i have tried Version 50.0.2661.94 m of google chrome but its good for information at your chrome version its not support so its not browser compatible.

Comment: Yeah, my Chrome 49.0.2623.112 m is probably totally outdated...

Comment: Ooh it mean in old version of chrome not support the script